# validate date after current datetime v-validate in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to validate datetime field

```
<datetime v-validate="'before:2016-05-25|date_format:yyyy-MM-dd|required'" format="YYYY-MM-DD" name="DateTime" width="100px" id="DateTime" :class="['form-control', {'is-invalid': errors.has('DateTime')}]" v-model="DateTime" ></datetime>
```

This part is working and validating also.

This is only accepting and validation date but i want to enter time also, when i enter yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s it does not validate date time anymore and i want to make this date `before:2016-05-25`  dynamic it should get the current date time.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is your `date_format` pattern string for the time (`H:i:s`):

- `H` is the pattern for **hour** (not zero-padded)
- `i` is the pattern for **ISO day of the week**
- `s` is the pattern for **seconds** (not zero-padded)

But time is usually shown as `HH:mm:ss`:

- `HH` is the pattern for **hour** (zero-padded)
- `mm` is the pattern for **minutes** (zero-padded)
- `ss` is the pattern for **seconds** (zero-padded)

Also, the `before` param must match the `date_format` pattern string, so if a time pattern were included, the `before` param would also need to include a time value.

For example, to validate a date before `2016-MAY-25` at `12:30pm`:

```html
<datetime v-validate="'before:2016-05-25 12:30:00|date_format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss|required'">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-before-date-time-urxu4?file=/src/App.vue)